# Keeping a rat as a housepet

Tags: halacha, animals

Is there any conflict within Torah law that wouldn't allow keeping a rat (or rather a few of them) in a cage in your room as a pet?

Comment: Have you done any research which would lead you to believe that there is a problem? https://animalsinhalacha.wordpress.com/category/pets/

Comment: Admittetly, I have not. It was somewhat of a preventive question but apparently there is no problem whatsoever to have any animal as a pet. As long as you don't eat it, even a pig could be hold as a pet (granted you purify yourself in water after every touch)

Comment: About pigs, see in Talmud Bava Qama 82b

Comment: @Anonymous you should wash your hands for sanitary reasons after touching any animal, but that has nothing to do with purification and there's nothing special about pigs.

Comment: @Anonymous about "any animal", don't get a tiger or alligator, for obvious reasons.  This is both halacha and common sense.

Comment: I don't know much about rat feces. But, there's a general rule that one may not recite certain prayers where there is a foul odor, esp. from feces. I don't recommend that you let your rats race around your house. They leave loads of droppings, and you'll be the loser in the rat race.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are halachic considerations for owning pets - like the limitation on certain kinds of dangerous animals, feeding them, shabbos, etc enumerated [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/halacha/jachter_1.htm), the straightforward answer to whether you may have a pet rat is that it is permitted. However, you mentioned that you are in a student dormitory, so you want to ensure owning a pet doesn't break any of the institution's rules which would pose a choshen mishpat question.

Comment: I am not sure the OP mentioned a dorm

Comment: @mbloch I did - as a comment though. And for some strange reason my comment was deleted. Anyways, thanks for the answer. Concerning Shabbos - preparing a larger quantity of food than usual beforehand should solve the problem. I'm not sure whether it is permitted by the administration of the dormitary, though. Obviously, a dog is entire different case. But a rat as a pet stays in the room.